# Memory usage in powershell

Tags: powershell, memory

I am trying to use Powershell to handle the mundane tasks surrounding running many, many iterations of a chemical model, with slightly differing input files. My powershell script creates a directory, copies the model and input files into the directory, and calls the model, which writes a single output file. Once the model is finished,  the script iterates one more time through the loop and does everything again (I have included the script below). My problem is that the memory usage of powershell continually rises, until all the RAM is occupied. Calling the model directly (i.e. simply clicking on the .exe file) produces no such issues, it uses very little memory. What unnecessary information is powershell remembering and how can I force it to keep the memory clear? I'm new to Powershell, so very simple answers, with basically no assumed prior knowledge would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for your help,

```
#say where the input and the output should be found:

$source='C:\a_directory_with_input_files'
$destination='C:\somewhere_for_model_output'

#unique name for this particular set of runs:
$suffix='sheath_data_v2_NH3_NO3_AIM'
$suffix2='AIM_sizes_NH3'

$names= '17_exp1' , '17_exp2',  '18_exp2',  '20am_exp1', '20am_exp2' , '20pm_exp1',  '20pm_exp2',  '20pm_exp3',  '21_exp1', '21_exp2',  '21_exp3', '05_exp1', '05_exp2', '07_exp1', '07_exp2', '07_exp3'

#find the bits of name for the directories:
ForEach ($i in $names)
{

echo $i
if ($i -eq '17_exp1') {$fn='17_11_2013_15_00-15_41_expa1_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '17_exp2') {$fn='17_11_2013_16_59-17_49_expa2_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '18_exp2') {$fn='18_11_2013_04_22-05_30_expa2_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '20am_exp1') {$fn='20_11_2013_02_26-03_19_expa1_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '20am_exp2') {$fn='20_11_2013_08_32-09_15_expa2_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '20pm_exp1') {$fn='20_11_2013_1508-1551_expa1_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '20pm_exp2') {$fn='20_11_2013_2015-2110_expa2_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '20pm_exp3') {$fn='20_11_2013_2240-2335_expa3_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '21_exp1')   {$fn='21_11_2013_03_51-04_58_expa1_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '21_exp2') {$fn='21_11_2013_06_52-07_44_expa2_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '21_exp3') {$fn='21_11_2013_08_57-09_53_expa3_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '05_exp1') {$fn='05_12_2013_11_59-12_40_expa1_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '05_exp2') {$fn='05_12_2013_13_53-14_30_expa2_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '07_exp1') {$fn='07_12_2013_10_04-10_45_expa1_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '07_exp2') {$fn='07_12_2013_11_26-12_06_expa2_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '07_exp3') {$fn='07_12_2013_12_58-13_40_expa3_NH4'}
if ($i -eq '25_pt1_C9_exp1') {$fn='25_09_2014_19_40-20_15_expa1'}
if ($i -eq '25_pt1_C9_exp2') {$fn='25_09_2014_21_00-21_31_expa2'}
if ($i -eq '25_pt1_C9_exp3') {$fn='25_09_2014_22_11-22_41_expa3'}
if ($i -eq '28_pt1_C9_exp1') {$fn='28_09_2014_16_40-17_06_expa1'}
if ($i -eq '28_pt1_C9_exp2') {$fn='28_09_2014_17_44-18_10_expa2'}
if ($i -eq '28_pt1_C9_exp3') {$fn='28_09_2014_18_52-19_15_expa3'}
if ($i -eq '28_pt1_C9_exp4') {$fn='28_09_2014_19_54-20_20_expa4'}
if ($i -eq '24_pt2_C9_exp1') {$fn='24_09_2014_16_22-16_50_expa1'}
if ($i -eq '24_pt2_C9_exp2') {$fn='24_09_2014_17_35-18_00_expa2'}
if ($i -eq '24_pt2_C9_exp3') {$fn='24_09_2014_18_47-19_15_expa3'}
if ($i -eq '25_pt2_C9_exp1') {$fn='25_09_2014_23_45-00_10_expa1'}
if ($i -eq '25_pt2_C9_exp2') {$fn='26_09_2014_01_02-01_30_expa2'}
if ($i -eq '25_pt2_C9_exp3') {$fn='26_09_2014_02_14-02_40_expa3'}
if ($i -eq '28_pt2_C9_exp1') {$fn='28_09_2014_20_55-21_20_expa1'}
if ($i -eq '28_pt2_C9_exp2') {$fn='28_09_2014_22_12-22_41_expa2'}
if ($i -eq '28_pt2_C9_exp3') {$fn='28_09_2014_23_31-23_55_expa3'}


#create the new directory, and copy input and model files into it:
$new_dir=$i+$suffix
echo $new_dir

new-item $destination\$new_dir -itemtype directory

copy-item $source\work\PSI\CLOUD\Windows_modelling\models\chamber_model_$suffix2".exe" $destination\$new_dir\

copy-item $source\work\PSI\CLOUD\Windows_modelling\expansion_input_files\input_chamber_$fn.dat $destination\$new_dir\input_chamber.dat
copy-item $source\work\PSI\CLOUD\Windows_modelling\libraries_and_stuff\* $destination\$new_dir\
copy-item $source\work\PSI\CLOUD\Windows_modelling\AIM_input\AMS_frac_$fn$suffix.dat $destination\$new_dir\AMS_frac.dat
copy-item $source\work\PSI\CLOUD\Windows_modelling\AIM_input\dist_$fn$suffix.dat $destination\$new_dir\dist.dat
copy-item $source\work\PSI\CLOUD\Windows_modelling\AIM_input\traj_$fn$suffix.dat $destination\$new_dir\traj.dat
copy-item $source\work\PSI\CLOUD\Windows_modelling\AIM_input\*$fn$suffix.dat $destination\$new_dir\

#now go there:
cd $destination\$new_dir
# and call the model, dumping any of the stuff the model outputs to the screen:
$(
./chamber_model_AIM_sizes_NH3.exe
) | Out-Null

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the command `$(blah.exe) | out-null` this causes Powershell to retain all of the output of blah.exe in memory.  I tested on my system a one-line script:

`cmd /c "dir c:\*.* /s" | out-null`

Powershell memory usage does not climb.  But with:

`$(cmd /c "dir c:\*.* /s") | out-null`

Powershell memory starts climbing immediately and keeps climbing.